# Class inheritance in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, oop, class-hierarchy

I am solving this problem :

> Consider the following hierarchy of classes:
>
> ```
> class Person(object):     
>     def __init__(self, name):         
>         self.name = name     
>     def say(self, stuff):         
>         return self.name + ' says: ' + stuff     
>     def __str__(self):         
>         return self.name  
>
> class Lecturer(Person):     
>     def lecture(self, stuff):         
>         return 'I believe that ' + Person.say(self, stuff)  
>
> class Professor(Lecturer): 
>     def say(self, stuff): 
>         return self.name + ' says: ' + self.lecture(stuff)
>
> class ArrogantProfessor(Professor): 
>     def say(self, stuff): 
>         return 'It is obvious that ' + self.say(stuff)
> ```
>
> As written, this code leads to an infinite loop when using the
>   Arrogant Professor class.
>
> Change the definition of ArrogantProfessor so that the following
>   behavior is achieved:
>
> ```
> e = Person('eric') 
> le = Lecturer('eric') 
> pe = Professor('eric') 
> ae = ArrogantProfessor('eric')
>
> e.say('the sky is blue')              #returns   eric says: the sky is blue
>
> le.say('the sky is blue')             #returns   eric says: the sky is blue
>
> le.lecture('the sky is blue')         #returns   believe that eric says: the sky is blue
>
> pe.say('the sky is blue')             #returns   eric says: I believe that eric says: the sky is blue
>
> pe.lecture('the sky is blue')     #returns   believe that eric says: the sky is blue
>
> ae.say('the sky is blue')         #returns   eric says: It is obvious that eric says: the sky is blue
>
> ae.lecture('the sky is blue')     #returns   It is obvious that eric says: the sky is blue
> ```

My solution to this is:

```
class ArrogantProfessor(Person):
    def say(self, stuff):
        return Person.say(self, ' It is obvious that ') +  Person.say(self,stuff)
    def lecture(self, stuff):
        return 'It is obvious that  ' + Person.say(self, stuff)
```

But the checker gives only half marks for this solution. What is the mistake that I am making and what are the test cases on which this code fails? (I am new to python and learned about classes some time ago.)

Comment: Is that a typo in the solution for `le.lecture(‘the sky is blue’)`, or is there really the pronoun "I" missing?

Comment: @L3viathan that was a typo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably should use `super()` instead of hard-wiring the class `Person`:

```
class ArrogantProfessor(Person):
    def say(self, stuff):
        return super(ArrogantProfessor, self).say(self.lecture(stuff))
    def lecture(self, stuff):
        return 'It is obvious that ' + super(ArrogantProfessor, self).say(stuff)
```

Answer (score 4):

It was given that:

```
class ArrogantProfessor(Professor):
```

but you did this:

```
class ArrogantProfessor(Person):
```

which resulted in the halved grade.

Comment: Actually I first used Professor as the argument but that did not work so I changed that to Person

Comment: That was the goal of the assigment @johnsmith! To make you *think* how to make it work with `Professor`. Good question btw, you got my upvote.

Answer (score 2):

As a former grader of coding hw, I assume, you should have produced the desired output without making `ArrogantProfessor` a mere `Person`. After all, the class name indicates that it should still subclass `Professor`.

Answer (score 2):

He probably wants you to actually get the parent class. The way to do this is simple.

Python2/3:

```
class ArrogantProfessor(Professor):
    def say(self, stuff):
        return 'It is obvious that ' + super(ArrogantProfessor, self).say(stuff)
```

Python 3 only:

```
class ArrogantProfessor(Professor):
    def say(self, stuff):
        return 'It is obvious that ' + super().say(stuff)
```

In either case, `ae.say("something")` should return:

```
"It is obvious that eric says: I believe that eric says: something"
```

This is because the parent class is `Professor`, not `Person`.

Similarly, in your lecture class, you should do:

```
def lecture(self, stuff):
    return 'I believe that ' + super(Lecturer, self).say(self, stuff) # or the Python3 version if you're using that
```

It's not really clear what it is that you want, though.

Answer (score 2):

This should be:

```
class ArrogantProfessor( Professor ):
    def lecture(self, stuff):
        return 'It is obvious that ' +  Person.say(self,stuff)
```

You don't have to define `say()` in `ArrogantProfessor`, because it is already defined in `Professor`, and it will use the `lecture()` method defined in the child class.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit hard to say without knowing what they're trying to teach you. A likely guess is that you're being taught inheritance, and if they've gone over [super](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) it's likely that they want you to utilize it to have the ArrogantProfessor's output look like:

```
eric says: It is obvious that STUFF
```

Where STUFF is the string you're passing in.

Answer (score 0):

```
     class Professor(Lecturer): 
        def say(self, stuff): 
            return "Prof. " + self.name + ' says: ' + self.lecture(stuff)

     class ArrogantProfessor( Professor ):
        def lecture(self, stuff):         
            return 'It is obvious that I believe that ' + Person.say(self, stuff)
```

Comment: You should have context for your answer, not just code.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part, the correct answer is:

```
class ArrogantProfessor(Professor):
    def lecture(self, stuff):
        return 'It is obvious that ' +  Lecturer.lecture(self,stuff)
```

Answer (score 0):

for part one the code is:

```
class ArrogantProfessor( Professor ):
def lecture(self, stuff):
    return 'It is obvious that ' +  Person.say(self,stuff)
```

for part two the code  is:

```
class ArrogantProfessor(Professor):
def lecture(self, stuff):
    return 'It is obvious that I believe that ' +  Person.say(self,stuff)
```

for part three the code is:

```
class Professor(Lecturer):
 def say(self, stuff): 
     return 'Prof. ' + self.name + ' says: ' + self.lecture(stuff)
```

Hope it is usefull